# Pushing data into ko.observableArray

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, signalr

I'm having problems getting this to work.  I have a form in a partial view in which I would like to populate a select field from a ko.observableArray.  In my javascript i can see my incoming data being returned via signalR but for some reason it's not being pushed to my observableArray. Here is my javascript:

```
var AddAthleteToRosterVm = function(user) {
var self = this;

// reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub
var teamMangHub = $.connection.teamMangHub;

// Athlete and Team arrays for select list
self.Athletes = ko.observableArray();
self.Teams = new Array();

// assign athlete data
teamMangHub.client.getAthletes = function(data) {
    // populate Athletes array
    self.Athletes.push(data); // data is not being pushed here.  Athletes array remains empty.
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {

    // retrieve the athletes from the server
    teamMangHub.server.retrieveAthletes(user);

});
};
```

Here's my partial view:

```
<h3 class="text-center">Add Athlete To Roster</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddAthleteToRoster", "CoachRosterManagement", FormMethod.Post,
new {@class = "text-center", id="athleteToRosterForm"}))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <fieldset class="myFormSpace">
    <legend>Athlete Info</legend>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.InputAthleteToRoster.AthleteId)<br />
        <select name="InputAthleteToRoster.AthleteId" data-bind="options: Athletes, optionsText: 'FirstName', value: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Select'"></select>
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.InputAthleteToRoster.CoachesTeamId)<br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InputAthleteToRoster.CoachesTeamId,
        new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()), "Select")
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Add Athlete</button>
</fieldset>
}
```

and this is the script that applies the binding from the view that calls partial view:

```
@section scripts
{

<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/AddAthleteToRoster.js"></script>
<script>
    var user = "@User.Identity.Name";


    ko.applyBindings(new AddAthleteToRosterVm(user));
</script>

}
```

On a side note, when I change the Athlete array from a ko.observableArray to a standard array such as:

```
 self.Athletes = new Array();
```

then the data will get pushed, but it still will not render in the select field on my partial view.

Comment: how do you determine that the Athletes observableArray is empty? and what does the `data` you're trying to push look like?

Comment: When I step through the code the array is empty. the data is a complex object.  It's an array of objects with various fields that may or may not hold other objects.

Comment: To access an observableArray, you must add parentheses to it since it's actually a function: `self.Athletes().length`.

Comment: @Michael Best Where in the code should I exactly make that change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observableArray is probably not empty after pushing `data`; in order to inspect it, you need to inspect the result of `self.Athletes()`, since the [observableArray is a function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) (so self.Athletes itself will show as an empty array even if there are elements in it).

Assuming `data` is an array of objects, each representing an athlete, it's probably not binding to your select list properly because you're pushing all of your data into one array element with

```
self.Athletes.push(data);
```

Since data is an array itself, you'll want to append the elements of `data` like this instead:

```
self.Athletes.push.apply(self.Athletes, data);
```

(or maybe simply assign it with `self.Athletes(data)`, depending on your requirements).

Comment: Your first suggestion was the solution. It worked with self.Athletes.push.apply(self.Athletes, data); I tried your other suggestion as well, but that didn't work for whatever reason. I didn't see this scenario anywhere in the knockoutJs documentation. Thank you for support!

Comment: @user1206480 setting self.Athletes to a new observable probably doesn't trigger the knockout bindings, so it makes sense that it wouldn't work; it may be possible to trigger that manually (but I don't know knockout well enough to say how) - as a side note: it's considered best practice to create arrays like this: `var myArray = []` instead of using the constructor.

Comment: The assignment method is `self.Athletes(data)`.